# How to work WebSharper translator?

Tags: f#, websharper

Could anyone explain how to work WebSharper translator in conjunction with the F#? 
Is it translate F# code to JS itself or using F# compiler for it?

In second case, what F# compiler are doing when finds [] attribute in source? Does compiler generate functions in any case and in runtime construct JS as reflection from compiled bytecode or there something other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I develop WebSharper. Good question!

Roughly the compilation looks like this:

```
a.dll: a.fs b.fs c.fs
    fsc ...

a.dll.js: a.dll
    WebSharper.exe ..
```

When functions are annotated with `[<JavaScript>]`, which is an alias for `[<ReflectedDefinition>]`, the F# compiler does not only compile these functions to .NET IL, but also stores the representation of their syntax in the DLL metadata. This representation has type `Quotations.Expr` and can be recovered by reflection. Have a look at `Quotations.DerivedPatterns.MethodWithReflectedDefinition`.

WebSharper is therefore a source to source translator, and it is pretty direct (preserves lambdas, for example). In WebSharper 2.0 we have an intermediate Scheme-like language, but that is only there to help optimize the generated code.